# Difference between RF and BPMN2?

Tags: drools

I know this question is for the most part a moot point since RF files are no longer supported, but, as someone relatively new to the Drools environment working with a much older project, what is the difference between RF files and the newer BPMN2 processes (aside from RF being discontinued and the names)? Do they handle rule flow differently or is the difference mainly a different file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is the underlying XML that is being used to store the process as a file.  RuleFlow is a proprietary format, created by the Drools team, to store RuleFlow information.  Once the BPMN 2.0 specification was available (which fitted the requirements the team had), we switched to using the BPMN 2.0 specification instead of our proprietary format.

We see no disadvantages to using BPMN 2.0 compared to RF (the language has even become more expressive) and you can easily transform a RF to BPMN 2.0.

Execution will be identical, this is only about how the process is stored as an XML file.